# QuickSort Structure

Tags: c, structure, quicksort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>


struct prvok
{
    char data;
    prvok* dalsi;
};




// Returns the last node of the list
struct prvok *getTail(struct prvok *cur)
{
    while (cur != NULL && cur->dalsi != NULL)
        cur = cur->dalsi;
    return cur;
}

void vypis(prvok* prvy)
{
    prvok* aktualny = prvy; // do aktualneho sa prida posledny priradeny
    while (aktualny != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ", aktualny->data);
        aktualny = aktualny->dalsi;   
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int zisti_pocet(prvok* prvy)
{
    prvok* aktualny = prvy;
    int pocet = 0;
    while (aktualny != NULL)
    {
        pocet++;
        aktualny = aktualny->dalsi;
    }
    return pocet;
}


prvok* vymaz_zoznam(prvok* prvy)
{
    prvok* aktualny = prvy, *dalsi;
    while (aktualny != NULL) {
        // Najskor si musime odlozit smernik na dalsi prvok, lebo po vymazani by sme uz dalsi prvok neziskali
        dalsi = aktualny->dalsi;
        free(aktualny);
        aktualny = dalsi;
    }

    // Vrati NULL, kedze zoznam je teraz uz prazdny...
    return NULL;
}

// Vytvori novy prvok so zadanou hodnotou a vrati smernik na vytvoreny prvok
prvok* vytvor_prvok(char hodnota)
{
    prvok* novy_prvok = (prvok*)malloc(sizeof(prvok));
    novy_prvok->data = hodnota;
    novy_prvok->dalsi = NULL;
    return novy_prvok;
}

// Prida prvok na zaciatok zoznamu a vrati smernik na novy prvy prvok zoznamu
prvok* pridaj_na_zaciatok(prvok* prvy, char hodnota)
{
    prvok* novy_prvok = vytvor_prvok(hodnota);
    novy_prvok->dalsi = prvy;
    return novy_prvok;
}

// Partitions the list taking the last element as the pivot
struct prvok *partition(struct prvok *head, struct prvok *end,
struct prvok **newHead, struct prvok **newEnd)
{
    struct prvok *pivot = end;
    struct prvok *prev = NULL, *cur = head, *tail = pivot;

    // During partition, both the head and end of the list might change
    // which is updated in the newHead and newEnd variables
    while (cur != pivot)
    {
        if (cur->data < pivot->data)
        {
            // First node that has a value less than the pivot - becomes
            // the new head
            if ((*newHead) == NULL)
                (*newHead) = cur;

            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->dalsi;
        }
        else // If cur node is greater than pivot
        {
            // Move cur node to next of tail, and change tail
            if (prev)
                prev->dalsi = cur->dalsi;
            struct prvok *tmp = cur->dalsi;
            cur->dalsi = NULL;
            tail->dalsi = cur;
            tail = cur;
            cur = tmp;
        }
    }

    // If the pivot data is the smallest element in the current list,
    // pivot becomes the head
    if ((*newHead) == NULL)
        (*newHead) = pivot;

    // Update newEnd to the current last node
    (*newEnd) = tail;

    // Return the pivot node
    return pivot;
}


//here the sorting happens exclusive of the end node
struct prvok *quickSortRecur(struct prvok *head, struct prvok *end)
{
    // base condition
    if (!head || head == end)
        return head;

    prvok *newHead = NULL, *newEnd = NULL;

    // Partition the list, newHead and newEnd will be updated
    // by the partition function
    struct prvok *pivot = partition(head, end, &newHead, &newEnd);

    // If pivot is the smallest element - no need to recur for
    // the left part.
    if (newHead != pivot)
    {
        // Set the node before the pivot node as NULL
        struct prvok *tmp = newHead;
        while (tmp->dalsi != pivot)
            tmp = tmp->dalsi;
        tmp->dalsi = NULL;

        // Recur for the list before pivot
        newHead = quickSortRecur(newHead, tmp);

        // Change next of last node of the left half to pivot
        tmp = getTail(newHead);
        tmp->dalsi = pivot;
    }

    // Recur for the list after the pivot element
    pivot->dalsi = quickSortRecur(pivot->dalsi, newEnd);

    return newHead;
}

// The main function for quick sort. This is a wrapper over recursive
// function quickSortRecur()
void quickSort(struct prvok **headRef)
{
    (*headRef) = quickSortRecur(*headRef, getTail(*headRef));
    return;
}

void printList(struct prvok *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d  ", node->data);
        node = node->dalsi;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void main() {
    // Pridanie prvkov

    prvok* prvy = NULL;
    prvy = pridaj_na_zaciatok(prvy, "Lukas");
    prvy = pridaj_na_zaciatok(prvy,  "Chuj");
    prvy = pridaj_na_zaciatok(prvy, "Somar");
    prvy = pridaj_na_zaciatok(prvy, "Amal");
    prvy = pridaj_na_zaciatok(prvy, "Jamal");


    printf("Zoznam:\n");
    printf("\n");
    vypis(prvy);


    int pocet = zisti_pocet(prvy);


    printf("Zoznam:\n");
    printf("\n");
    vypis(prvy);

    quickSort(&prvy);
    printList(prvy);


    prvy = vymaz_zoznam(prvy);
}
```

Could someone help me with this code. I want to sort the names alphabetically using QuickSort. 
I do not know whether that my code is correct and can be used for sorting word by Alphabetical.
If someone had a code suitable for this situation could give him here.

Comment: Did you try to compile the code ? Where there error ? Is the code not behaving as expected ? In short *what's the problem ?*

Comment: should be `char *data;`